# Sencha Touch: Prevent multiple concurrent transitions

Tags: sencha-touch

QA just filed a real doozy of a bug, and I'm scratching my head how to fix it.

If two buttons, e.g. back, and search are pressed at the same time, each will invoke `Ext.dispatch`, causing two simultaneous opposing transitions! This totally !@#$s up the layout, rendering the app unusable.

This is really a general problem with touch-enabled apps... with multiple fingers hovering over the screen, the user can easily trigger weird and totally incompatible action combinations, and the app needs to accept only one at a time. Is there any way to handle this situation gracefully in Sencha Touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by listening to the `before-dispatch` event, and canceling it if there is a dispatch already in progress.

```
Ext.regApplication(...
    this._isDispatching = false,

    launch: function() {
        Ext.Dispatcher.on('before-dispatch', function () {
            var me;
            if (this._isDispatching)
                return false;
            else {
                this._isDispatching = true;
                me = this;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    me._isDispatching = false;
                }, 500);
                return true;
            }
        }, this);
    }
```

Yes, the 500ms delay is definitely hacky, but I couldn't think of a more robust way of detecting when the transition has completed. There is no `after-dispatch` event, and the `dispatch` event fires before the transition has completed.

Hope this helps someone.